# "binary is not a Firefox executable" error using Selenium on Windows in Python

Tags: selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

driver_service = Service(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe")

options = Options()
options.binary_location = executable_path=r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_service, options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Geckodriver seems to be working (as per the geckodriver.log), but I get this error message:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

I have checked that the path to firefox.exe is correct. I have updated Selenium, I also made sure I have the latest versions of both Firefox and Geckodriver, I don't know what should I do to make it past this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an error in your code when specifying the path of the Firefox binary file.

Here the correct code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# here the paths of the two binaries 
geckodriver_path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe"
firefox_binary_path = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"

driver_service = Service(executable_path=geckodriver_path)

options = Options()
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=driver_service, options=options)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: I have tried with this code, but still getting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It resolved by updating to the latest version of selenium 4.16.0.